# Vaadin InvientChart widgetset error

Tags: gwt, vaadin

can someone explain me how to start with InvientChart  add-on? I have do something like this :

- Make a new Vaadin Project
- Add the jar to WebContent/WEB-INF/lib
- Add jquery.js and highchart.js to WebContent/js folder
- Create a class that extend ApplicationServlet and add url to above js file
- Change the servlet class in web.xml
- Make a InvientPie class link
- Run the project and compile the widgetset

I'm getting this error :

Failed to load the widgetset: /chartProject/VAADIN/widgetsets/com.example.chartProject.widgetset.ChartProjectWidgetset/com.example.chartProject.widgetset.ChartProjectWidgetset.nocache.js?1368453503030

I'm using InvientCharts 0.8.6 , Vaadin 6.8.5, gwt-dev 2.3.0, gwt-user 2.3.0

Am I missing something? Can someone please tell me the right sequence to use this add-on clearly. Thanks

Edit : here is my widgetset.xml after compile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">

<module>
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet" />

    <!--
     Uncomment the following to compile the widgetset for one browser only.
     This can reduce the GWT compilation time significantly when debugging.
     The line should be commented out before deployment to production
     environments.

     Multiple browsers can be specified for GWT 1.7 as a comma separated
     list. The supported user agents at the moment of writing were:
     ie6,ie8,gecko,gecko1_8,safari,opera

     The value gecko1_8 is used for Firefox 3 and later and safari is used for
     webkit based browsers including Google Chrome.
    -->
    <!-- <set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8"/> -->

</module>
```

Comment: It should work the way you described.
What is strange is the /chartProject/ part in the failed to load URL. I think it should directly be /VAADIN/ since it is relative to the app location. Does the error shows up when you start your vaadin app or only when you wish to show the chart?

Comment: The error shows up when I start the application. And when I try to compile using the eclipse toolbar (or ctrl 6) it give me another error

Error compiling widgetset:
java.io.IOException - Cannot run program "C:\Program Files(x86)\eclipse-jee-juno-win32\eclipse\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Program Files(x86)\workspace\chartProject"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: I've found the nocache.js at vaadin library. The strange thing is why my app requesting 

VAADIN/widgetsets/com.example.chartt.widgetset.CharttWidgetset/com.example.chartt.widgetset.CharttWidgetset.nocache.js

instead of

VAADIN\widgetsets\com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet\com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet.nocache.js

am I misconfiguring something?

Comment: The widgetset is not compiled correctly, this is your problem.
You have to make sure it compiles correctly, it will then generate the required js files.

Comment: thanks. how to make sure it compiles correctly?

Comment: This one ?

https://vaadin.com/de/forum#!/thread/2546882